# Error in starting the application through nodemon

Tags: express, nodemon

I am building a full stack app and after a lot of waste efforts I came here to ask you guys about the following error.

Plus, I do know what this error means as I have read about it but still I am unable to figure out the flaw that is present in somewhere.

Request you to help me out so that I can continue my work at pace.

**Folder Architecture:**

**nearbywi-fi(Main Directory):** bin, node_modules, public, server, app.js, bower.js
on, package.json, procfile, yarn-error.log, package-lock.json

**Public:** bootstrap, images, javascripts, stylesheets

**server:** controllers, routes, views

**ERROR:**

```
pinkman@pinkman:~/nearbywi-fi$ nodemon
[nodemon] 1.12.5
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
module.js:544
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/pinkman/nearbywi-fi/index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:682:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:613:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrlLocations = require('./controllers/locations');
var ctrlOthers = require('./controllers/others');

router.get('/', ctrlLocations.homelist);
router.get('/location', ctrlLocations.locationInfo);
router.get('/location/review/new', ctrlLocations.addReview);

router.get('/about', ctrlOthers.about);

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./server/routes/index');
var users = require('./server/routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
});
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
});
});


module.exports = app;
```

**package.json**

```
{
 "name": "Nearbywi-fi",
 "version": "v1.3.2",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node ./bin/www",
 "postinstall": "node -e \"try { require('fs').symlinkSync(require('path').resolve('node_modules/@bower_components'), 'bower_components', 'junction') } catch (e) { }\""},
  "dependencies": {
  "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
  "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
  "debug": "~2.6.9",
  "express": "~4.15.5",
  "jade": "^1.11.0",
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "jstransformer": "^1.0.0",
  "morgan": "~1.9.0",
  "nodemon": "^1.12.5",
  "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
  "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "vivek Gupta",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
  "engines": {
  "yarn": ">= 1.0.0"
  }
 }
```

Comment: Is `Index.js` with a capital "I" a typo or not?

Comment: No small i: index.js
I have changed it.

Comment: Ah. It's because you're not specifying the file you want nodemon to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `nodemon` by itself will try and run index.js

In your case, this file is a route, not the main application, and it's not even in the root directory. So you want to run `nodemon app.js`

This is pretty much summed up in the log and your error:

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Error: Cannot find module '/home/pinkman/nearbywi-fi/index.js'
```

## Edit:

Based on the package.json that you've provided, it seems the entry point should actually be `"./bin/www"`, so you'll want `"nodemon ./bin/www"` instead.

Also, in your package.json, it says `"main": "index.js",` but this should be `"main": "bin/www",`

Comment: shall I update my package.json and bower.json file main attribute with app.js? would that help ? Though the solutions removed the error but still not starting the app on localhost.

Comment: This is what it is stuck at:

pinkman@pinkman:~/nearbywi-fi$ nodemon app.js
[nodemon] 1.12.5
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Comment: and if I am running with npm start it runs fine. I don't know why nodemon is not working.

Comment: Your nodemon log above is how it should look

Comment: Have you specified your `main` file in package.json? I admittedly don't know whether it respects that or not, but it _should_

Comment: if the log is supposed to look like this then I am not getting any output on localhost:3000 but when I run "npm start" in terminal I get my localhost working atleast.

Comment: Yes. I have specified main as index.js as it was earlier. nodemon used to fetch the file specified in the main attribute, when it fails to find the file in default runway. I thought adding a path to this main attribute would help but didn't work that way.

Comment: Oh sorry, seems I missed the "clean exit" bit. Although I've just noticed that you don't actually have an `app.listen(3000)` in your code... :/ Which more questions why you're getting output with npm start when really you shouldn't, ha. Can you post your package.json to the question please, and I'll update my answer accordingly!

Comment: Though output is not exactly what I am expecting as my ui is not at all as desired right now but that's not a matter of a bug right? I hope to get it fixed with some adjustments.

Comment: Ahhhh it's `./bin/www` not `app.js`

Comment: And your package.json is indeed using index.js, which isn't correct

Comment: got you. but one question cant I leave main as empty? when I have nodemon referring to my npm stsrt file?

Comment: and what about app.listen()??

Comment: Really, the `npm start` definition in your package.json isn't required, and will automatically use the `main` attribute. I was trying to work out why your `app.js` doesn't have a listen directive, but that's because it's defined within another javascript file, `bin/www`. Just the way express does things these days if you use their cli builder